# jQuery UI Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wwqpq/) is the code from my project where I am using a datepicker. The jQuery menubar works but the datepicker doesnt. What am I missing? Also, how do I get the menubar center aligned?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wwqpq/

Comment: It looks messed up. But it seems your added libraries don't have `datepicker` defined. Please check them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not loading `jquery.ui.datepicker.js`

**Add the following line after loading** `jquery.ui.core.js`

```
<script src="http://view.jqueryui.com/menubar/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

See Updated jsfiddle (**fixed**): http://jsfiddle.net/CcjPh/

**Note:** You should probably download the jQuery files and host them yourself rather than using jqueryui.com / jquery.com as a source.

Comment: For some reason jQuery did not allow linking from that file to jsfiddle. It was returning an HTTP 403 error. Please see updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CcjPh/

Comment: Thank you so much!
Could you please help me in getting the menubar center aligned? I tried it but it dint workout.